# Question about a nonhomogeneous recurrence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Im trying to solve this nonhomogenous recurrence: 
[link to the nonhomogeneous recurrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gczIO.png)

The homogeneous part is **$A*(-5)^n + B*2^n$**

The part that is bothering me is  **$7 * 5^n$** does that translate to $Cn * 5^n$ ?

Comment: It is $$a_n=c_1 (-2)^n+c_2 5^n-\frac{1}{7} 5^{n+1} \left(5 (-1)^{2
   n}-7 n\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions to the associated homogeneous equation are given by
$$r^2-3r-10=0$$
$$(r+2)(r-5)=0$$
$$r=-2,5$$
Hence we have the complementary function
$$c_n=A(-2)^n+B(5)^n$$
Given this information the particular function will be of the form
$$p_n=Cn(5)^n$$
So plugging this into the original equation, we then have
$$Cn(5)^n-3C(n-1)(5)^{n-1}-10C(n-2)(5)^{n-2}=7(5)^n$$
$$\left(1-\frac35-\frac25\right)Cn(5)^n+\left(\frac35+\frac45\right)C(5)^n=7(5)^n$$
$$\frac75C(5)^n=7(5)^n$$
$$\therefore C=5$$
So the general solution is
$$a_n=c_n+p_n=A(-2)^n+(B+5n)(5)^n$$